# How to make typescript strict option work completely?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, express, typescript-typings

I have enforced strict option but still typescript is not complaining for not defining types for port,req,res in the snippet. I am using Vscode and how to enforce it completely.

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello !');
});
app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "strict": true,    
  "lib": ["es2015"],
  "--isolatedModules":true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--strict` [compiler option](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options) for tsc is a shorthand for a bunch of individual compiler options, *none of which require you to annotate variables/parameters everywhere*.  The compiler is perfectly happy to infer types for unannotated variables and parameters, and most of the time this is the preferred convention.  The only time `--strict` will really complain about a missing annotation is if the compiler can't infer a good type for it and falls back to using [`any`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any).  But that's just the `--noImplicitAny` trying to save you from accidentally using the unsafe `any` type, not trying to remind you to annotate everything.

In your code above, the unannotated `app` constant is inferred to be of type `Express`; `port` is inferred as type `3000`, and `req` and `res` are inferred to be of type `Request` and `Response`, as if you had annotated them yourself like this:

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
const app: Express = express();
const port: 3000 = 3000;
app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send('Hello !');
});
```

The only place the compiler is unhappy is in the `app.listen()` callback of type `Function`, where there is no contextual type for the  `err` parameter and the compiler picks `any`.  So here is the only place you should need to annotate:

```
app.listen(port, (err: any) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

---

That being said, if you want a complaint for every unannotated variable or parameter, you should use a linter like [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) or [ESLint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint#table-of-contents) alongside tsc.

If you use TSLint, you can enable [the `typedef` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/), which "requires type definitions to exist."  There are sub-options specifically targeting the declaration of function parameters (`"parameter"` and `"arrow-parameter"`) and of variables (`"variable-declaration" and "variable-declaration-ignore-function"`).

If you use ESLint, you can enable its [`typedef` rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/typedef.md), which "requires type annotations to exist".  Again, there are sub-options for function parameters (`"parameter"` and `"arrowParameter"`) and variable declaration (`"variableDeclaration"`).

Either one of those should get you the behavior you want.  But again, the conventional wisdom is that type inference is a good thing.  As ESLint's `typedef` docs say: "if you do not consider the cost of writing unnecessary type annotations reasonable, then do not use this rule."

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAUwB5iggzugNHA3nAURTUxwCUEBHAVwxnI0gDt0E4BfOAMyghDgDkyVBnQCA3AChJAYwgt4AQzBgAXIWKi4AXkSbMACgCUUuQriRY6gMwAGezrh37U5WAB0AcwQwDAgPQCOAZolOoUNHQ4JOGM8qxGOgB8eJJwcCTurEwAJn4AEggANkUQcACEAiaS7NVu7kXA6DAITAaW9HAGCFBQ6opMAJ6J2im4aXDAXF09UIn4E+loMNRQTHBm6BBFCO6z0N291ensE8ur65vbu6WeBgAGrFAAbj2T6HCNza3ATJ5w8jgABJcB12PdqrVxEA)